# What are some good practices when returning LARGE amounts of data from an ASP.net web service?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, web-services

I'm currently working on some web services for a client of ours. Before we make it available to them we'd like to optimize performance of our database calls, as very LARGE amounts of data can potentially be returned. (could be tens of thousands of objects, could be millions, each object containing about 12 lists of other objects)

We don't want to strain our servers, nor do we want to limit the web service unnecessarily.

One of the web service methods returns all data within a specified date range, I was thinking that if the amount of data being returned was larger than a set amount, return a message saying something like:

"Data too large, please reduce date range"

Is limiting the user's scope like that a good idea??

I have to limit the amount of data our client can retrieve in one shot, but still keep at as convenient as possible for them. I mean, they're programmers too so it doesn't have to be too simple, but simple enough to use.

What are some good practices concerning returning large amount of data through a web service??

Thanks!

Comment: Tens of thousands of what exactly? Gigabytes, strings, booleans? And are you definitely using MySql with .NET?

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. Tens of thousands of objects, each containing lists of records from maybe 12 different tables. It's hard to say exactly what kinds of datatypes, mostly strings.

Comment: I would have the service return a Response object that has an isSuccessful boolean, and an error code (or text).  The consumer can check the successfullness (it's a word) of the transaction, and switch on the error code to determine what to do next.  I would NOT recommend limiting off of records returned, because that would be based on the dataset, instead do something consistent like a date range, so they know they will ALWAYS get results back.

Comment: You are asking if it is a good idea to display an error message?

Comment: Thanks David. Yes our situations are quite different. In my case I can't have a fixed allowable date range as the amount of data can vary greatly for a one week period for example. @Lix - No, that was a specific idea I thought I could implement to reduce the amount of data being sent back (I just wanted to know if it was a good idea to limit the client's scope, not specifically if I could return an error message) My overall question is asking about good practices for sending large amounts of data.

Comment: You might want to think about rewording your post to accentuate that.  As it stands you question appears to be about the error message.

Comment: off topic? seriously? It makes me sad to see what is happening to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to adapt the common technique of paging data displayed in a list or grid. The call to the database specifies the number of records to return, and the page number.

So, for example, if they are displaying 10 records on a page, only 10 records will be returned for display. Records 1 - 10 (or 0 - 9, if you prefer) are returned for page 1, and 11 - 20 for page 2, and so on.

Also often returned is the total number of records available.

This way, the user can continue scrolling through a large number of records, or they can choose to refine their search criteria to yield a smaller resultset.

You could consider this kind of **paging or chunking** approach for your web service. The web service call supplies the number of records to be sent in each chunk, and the "page" or "chunk" number. The web service returns the requested records, along with the total number of records available.

With this approach, the developer who is consuming the web service remains in control.

The calling code can be placed in a loop so that it continues requesting chunks, if that behavior is desirable. If someone really wants a truckload of records, they can just set the number of records argument to be a very large number (or you could make that an optional parameter, and return everything if it is null, zero, empty).

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your needs.  This seems more of a design question than a coding question to me, but in our systems we have two approaches.  I'll share them to give you some ideas to consider.

- In the first one, we're the ones providing the data.  We allow customers to download transaction data on their accounts, and for some customers this can be a fairly large amount of data.  We limit them to X days worth of data, and they are fine with this.
- In the second one, we're consuming data from a web service from an established vendor that tracks vehicle location data, and other data of interest to our dispatchers and management.  Every truck in our fleet gives regular updates of their geolocation, plus other data (loading/unloading/driver on break, etc)

  - In these web services, we request a date range, and the service returns a set limit of records (1000 records per call).
  - In addition to passing in the date range, we pass in a "position" integer field.  On the first call the "position" is set to zero.
  - The web service returns a "More Data Exists" boolean field.
  - If "More Data Exists"=true, then we call the web service again with the "position" parameter incremented, and repeat until "More Data Exists" = false  (It's a simple while loop in our code)

I think the first one is great for either programmers OR end users.  The second works fine when dealing with programmers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I like the second approach that you mentioned. But how much is it really reducing strain on our servers if it's just looped on the client side??

Comment: It's not, except that there's a brief pause while my program parses the retreived data, and before it goes and gets the next batch.  That frees up the server for other calls to get in there in-between calls.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like potentially lot of data for a webservice.

But here's a page from MSDN which talks about setting up the server to send/receive 'large' volumes of data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can give them a chunk of data per time like (1000 obj) They have to specified a start index and amount of data they want and you just use that to pull your data. 
In SQL there is TAKE and Skip that can do this easy.